# Load balancing with nginx

Tags: performance, web-services, nginx, load-balancing, nginx-config

I want to stop serving requests to my back end servers if the load on those servers goes above a certain level. Anyone who is already surfing the site will still get routed but new connection will be sent to a static server busy page until the load drops below a pre determined level.

I can use cookies to let the current customers in but I can't find information on how to to routing based on a custom load metric.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

Nginx has an [HTTP Upstream](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule) module for load balancing. Checking the responsiveness of the backend servers is done with the `max_fails` and `fail_timeout` options. Routing to an alternate page when no backends are available is done with the `backup` option. I recommend translating your load metrics into the options that Nginx supplies.

Let's say though that Nginx is still seeing the backend as being "up" when the load is higher than you want. You may be able to adjust that further by tuning the max connections of the backend servers. So, maybe the backend servers can only handle 5 connections before the load is too high, so you tune it only allow 5 connections. Then on the front-end, Nginx will time-out immediately when trying to send a sixth connection, and mark that server as inoperative.

Comment: Thanks for you answer - perhaps I can use the $upstream_response_time to manage this. I could calculate the average response time across all the servers, if that drops to some unacceptable level then route the request to a busy page otherwise let it through. Using the "least_conn" balance option the request would be passed to the server with the least connections and, hopefully, the least load.

Comment: Sounds good. I think the simplicity of making the standard solution work for you will be win a if you are able to tune it to your needs.

Comment: I can't see a way to get nginx to stop serving at some pre defined load level without forking the load balancing module and doing something with that. I don't want the backend server return server busy as by then the load will be too high...

Comment: It's not necessarily true that having the backend server return "busy" mean that the load is too high. With good tuning of the max processes, it could start rejecting new connections when it reaches a level that it comfortably handle (rather than an overloaded level).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to handle this outside of Nginx. Software like Nagios can not only monitor load, but can also [proactively trigger actions](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/eventhandlers.html) based on the monitor it does.

You can generate your Nginx configs from a template that has options to mark each upstream node as up or down. When a monitor detects that the upstream load is too high, it could re-generate the Nginx config from the template as appropriate and then reload Nginx.

A lightweight version of the same idea could done with a script that runs on the same machine as your Nagios server, and performs simple monitoring as well as the config file updates.